# This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

> My MacBook Pro version : macOS MOJAVE version 10.14.5
>
> My node version : v10.16.0
>
> My npm version : 6.9.0

Problem is whenever I install or create npm app via terminal it always occurs an error like : This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above. I didn't get any perfect answer yet please help me with this.

I will tell you about my command like

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

but I always get an error when I type `npm start`.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Did you look at the output above for an error message? Post the full output

Comment: Are you creating the project in your root folder? If so, you need system privileges (`sudo`) to create directories and files.

Answer (score 0):

This problem arises from the npm package which is incompatible with the react package you have.

Try Updating both package or uninstall the package which is causing this problem.